# How to set the folder name of the installation folder set to default even though directory has been changed in ISWIX?

Tags: wix, iswix

I am using ISWIX plugin based on WIX to create Windows MSI Installer. I want to set the folder name of the installation folder to Manufacturer/MyAPPNAME. It works fine if the user doesn't change the directory. But if the user changes the directory then the MYAPPNAME folder name is not present in the text box representing the installation path. I want my installer to set the MyAPPNAME folder along with MANUFACTURER folder by default even if the user changes the installation directory. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure we could have a long, drawn out conversation about what's the best practice for these kinds of deployment decisions, but for now I'll just tell you how to do what you want to do...

You could add a custom action that fires after the user selects the install path and appends the "Manufacturer/MyAPPNAME" path.

CustomAction - Type:51 - Source:[INSTALLDIR] - Target:[INSTALLDIR][Manufacturer]\[MyAPPNAME]

(This is assuming [INSTALLDIR] already has an ending path separator "\")

Comment: When the custom action will be performed? Can you please give the code snippet for WIX?